# Cross-platform make system supporting 32/64 bit targets on Windows and Linux

Tags: windows, visual-studio, makefile, cmake, bakefile

I'm looking for a make system, along the lines of CMake or Bakefile, that supports the generation of Visual Studio project files and makefiles (targetting Linux) dual targeting x86 and x64 (in the same project/make file).

I've looked at CMake and Bakefile and they both appear to have limitations in this respect; they both appear to not support multiple targets (Bakefile doesn't even seem to support 64bit  vcproj).

Are there any other tools, open source or paid, that may be suitable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a (simple) [patch for Bakefile](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.sysutils.bakefile.devel/1372/focus=1374) that enables it -- you may be able to help with testing it.

Comment: Great, this address the problem

Answer (score 0):

CMake can generate code multiple targets architectures (32 and 64 bit, say) on different platforms (win and linux, say).  I can also use qmake (part of [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/)) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's a higher level tool and that you probably already know about it, I would propose [SCons](http://www.scons.org/).